# Separable and diffuse probability space is standard

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, almost-everywhere

Let $(X,\mathcal{N},\mu)$ be a complete probability space, and assume that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{N}$ has no atoms, that is, for every set $A \in \mathcal{N}$ with $\mu(A) > 0$ there is a set $B \in \mathcal{N}$ with $B \subset A$ and $0 < \mu(B) < \mu(A)$.

> If $(X,\mathcal{N},\mu)$ is separable, that is, if one can find a countable family of elements $\{A_n\} \subset \mathcal{N}$ such that for every $B \in \mathcal{N}$ there exists $i$ with $\mu(A_i \Delta B) = 0$, is $(X,\mathcal{N},\mu)$ almost isomorphic to a standard probability space?

I am aware of the following corollary in Fremlin's Volume 3 of Measure Theory:

**344K.** A measure space $(X,\mathcal{N},\mu)$ is isomorphic to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ iff it is an atomless countably separated compact (or perfect) complete probability space.

Here isomorphism is understood to be  measurable and inverse-measure-preserving bijection with measurable and inverse-measure-preserving inverse. I am not aware of a analogous condition for almost isomorphism. Indeed, I see no reason for $(X,\mathcal{N},\mu)$ to be countably separated in general, though one might try to pass to a quotient set of $X$ which makes the topology generated by the $\{A_n\}$ to be Hausdorff. Then, one still has to deal with compactness, and again a candidate for a compact family of measurable sets would be the $\{A_n\}$, and finiteness + completeness of the measure could somehow imply compactness, but I don't see it either.

For context, I'm reading A. Carderi's paper [Ultraproducts, weak equivalence and sofic entropy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03189.pdf), where in Lemma 2.16 he finds a separable $\sigma$-subalgebra $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathcal{N}$ with $(X,\mathcal{N},\mu)$ being a complete atomless probability space and to my understanding claims that $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is standard.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this would follow from Maharam's theorem, since $(X,\mathcal{N},\mu)$ would be almost isomorphic to copies of products of the interval, and those are completely determined by their Maharam type up to almost isomorphism. Since the Maharam type of the measure algebra of $(X,\mathcal{N},\mu)$ is $\aleph_0$, the result follows. But I couldn't find a reference for Maharam's theorem as stated. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharam%27s_theorem)